# Need help in SQL query to check a doctor exists for a visit

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have the following table data. For each visit n-number of patients and doctors are allowed.
For example, if a visit has 1 patient and 2 doctors there will be 3 records in this participants table.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH8xv.png)

I want a query to find the visits for which no providers are available. Please help me on that.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. Please use if some one has same scenario

```
select visit_id  from participants
group by visit_id
having count(provider_id) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t.visit_id
from mysterytablename t
where t.patient_id and t.provider_id is null and
    not exists (
        select 1
        from mysterytablename t2
        where t2.provider_id and t2.visit_id=t.visit_id
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working. But i found a better answer I believe. I will post it if some one needs